# iOS - Create an NSURL from an NSFileHandle or NSPipe

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am receiving a stream of encoded audio over the network, but there is a bunch of data mixed in so I need to receive the packets, strip out the audio then play the audio.

AVAudioPlayer, which may or may not be the best tool for this but it's the path I'm currently chasing, wants data from NSData or NSURL.  NSData won't work because it is a stream of data and I want it to start as soon as it arrives and continue playing.  My thought was:

```
NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
NSFileHandle *writeHandle = [pipe fileHandleForWriting];
NSFileHandle *readHandle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

// in network reception thread...
NSData *audioData = [packet getAudioData];
[writeHandle writeData:audioData];

// in audio thread...
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] init];
[url setResourceValue:NSURLFileResourceTypeNamedPipe 
               forKey:NSURLFileResourceTypeKey 
                error:&error];
// Connect the readHandle
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                               initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                               error:&error];
```

However, I don't know how to pass the `readHandle` into the URL.  How do I create an NSURL from an existing NSFileHandle?  Is there some better approach for this entirely?  Is there a way to write data into something that can become an NSURL?

The only real requirement is that I can play the audio as near real time as possible.  I don't want to queue up data for even a tenth of a second before it gets played.

Comment: What about creating a named pipe and creating a URL of that named pipe?

Comment: WTP - Thanks.  I like the idea and even searched for how to do it but didn't see anything about named pipes in iOS.  Suggestions?

Comment: iOS is a UNIX system based on Mac OS X, so it should be possible to use [`mkfifo`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/2/mkfifo/) to create a named pipe. Then you simply create an `NSURL` of that.

Comment: Good idea, good question - curious on the results....

Comment: I tried the mkfifo, but the `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]` blocked and would not progress.  I think AVAudioPlayer is going to create too much delay in my playback anyway so I'm going to lower level APIs.  Thanks for the thoughs and ideas.

Comment: i still hope someone answers this.  i'm also curious how to mkfifo…  i'm sure through nspipe.. but how?  nstask's IPC sucks.

Comment: @Schlameel It blocks because an open on a named pipe wants a writer to appear before returning.  To get immediate opening, you have to open with O_NONBLOCK, and get notified when the writer is ready.  `initWithContentsOfURL` is of no use anyway, because it wants to have access to the entire file, not just the pieces as it appears.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve an `NSFileHandle`'s URL because not all handles have a corresponding URL. Your example would appear to be one such example.